# How to use sub routes in react-router that match on query string or hash?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

More examples are definitely needed in the docs for this but basically I am after something like this for example:

```
<Route path="/" component={CoreLayout}>
  <IndexRoute component={IndexLayout} />
  <Route path="foo/bar" component={MyComponent}>
    <Route path="#baz=laa" component={SubComponent} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

I've tried importing history attribute and all sorts and cannot get it to match. Our issue is that we are building a new mobile site, keep the same paths as the desktop site, however we have some routes which are new on mobile and we want to add those using the hash.

If anybody has any ideas, would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you could match it by param name (see: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax).